# What does "Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file." mean?

Tags: python-poetry

When I run poetry commands, I get the message:

```
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
```

I don't remember setting such a thing, and I don't really see anything relevant in the pyproject.toml. What config file is poetry talking about?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can see current settings via `poetry config --list`. These settings are usually global settings. But it's also possible to have local settings due to a `poetry.toml` in the same folder as the `pyproject.toml`. Local configs can be set by a `poetry config --local <configsetting>`.

This is also described in the docs: https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/

A `poetry config virtualenvs.create true` is what you are looking for. This setting is the default value. So there is a good chance that you've changed it at some point.

Comment: In my case it is `virtualenvs.create = false` - but a grep for `virtualenvs.create` didn't turn up anything.