# PyCharm project cannot add poetry interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, python-poetry

- OS: win10
- PyCharm version: PyCharm Professional 2021.2.2
- Poetry version:  1.1.13
- Poetry plugin version: 1.1.5-212 (from koudai aono)

I have tried to build a new PyCharm project by poetry environment,
[image]
while setting up it showed
[image]

and cannot setup the interpreter.
Have anyone got the similar problem before and know how to solve this error?

**Update**
I have upgraded the PyCharm version to PyCharm Professional 2022.1.1 and the problem still remain.

Comment: What happens when you execute that command manually from a terminal?

Comment: @Brian I tried `poetry env info -p` in the project dir and it showed nothing, and `poetry env info` return the path which is global interpreter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I have fixed this problem.

Below is my debug steps, hope it can help those who are struggling in the same situation:

1. Posting a support report to `PyCharm team` with no responce
2. Searching for a lot of posts from communities
3. Creating a poetry project by terminal
4. Inside the project directory, I tried `poetry env info` and it showed that the local `virtualenv` is `NA`
5. Trying to create one by `poetry env use $(which python)`, yet it returned `Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589136/13345077) gave me a hint.
6. Typing `poetry config --list` and it showed that `virtualenvs.create = false`
7. Trying to enable the `virtualenv` creation by the command `poetry config virtualenvs.create true`
8. Restarted the `PyCharm IDE` and tried to add the interpreter again and **it WORKED!!**

I am not sure if the command `poetry config virtualenvs.create true` is permant or not.

Comment: In step 4, I didn't see NA. It shows __(vdocv) dev@npl:(old_repo_moving_process/doc-parser-build) % poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.15
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/nk/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/doc-parser-svc-yP2QnEEJ-py3.9
Valid:          False

System
Platform: darwin
OS:       posix
Python:   /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9___

Comment: even the create was true. Still the same error. Doesn't work even after restarting pycharm

Comment: You have to recreate the environment in PyCharm - another reason why this can happen is that the name of the package has changed in pyproject.toml, which means that poetry and pycharm no longer agree on what the correct environment is.